# How to configure a folder for custom Python App installed through CPanel?

Tags: python, logs, virtualenv

I installed my python script using Cpanel feature "Setup Python App".
I run my script in virtual environment created by CPanel:

```
/home4/apmcapit/virtualenv/apps/myapp/3.9/bin/python /home4/apmcapit/apps/myapp/myapp.py
```

It works fine except for files and logs. It saves logs files to root folder of my hosting. When my app tries to open a file folder for reading it also looking for it in root folder.
Question is how do I define a folder for logs and files? Default folder of the app.